# Mouse click events on a live stream with Opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv, mouseevent

i am new to opencv -python.
I want to draw a rectangle in a live stream video captured from my webcam. While drawing the rectangle,the video must freeze. I am successful in drawing a rectangle on a image,but i don't know how to do the same on a live video using opencv and python . Please help..

Comment: Please share what you done so far with piece of code.

Answer (score 3):

This is a code that I'm using to draw a rectange in videos.

The code works like that:

1. click on video and the script save the start point
2. click again and the script save the end point and draw the rectangle
3. click again to start drawing another retangle

   ```
   import numpy as np
   import cv2

   rect = (0,0,0,0)
   startPoint = False
   endPoint = False

   def on_mouse(event,x,y,flags,params):

       global rect,startPoint,endPoint

       # get mouse click
       if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:

           if startPoint == True and endPoint == True:
               startPoint = False
               endPoint = False
               rect = (0, 0, 0, 0)

           if startPoint == False:
               rect = (x, y, 0, 0)
               startPoint = True
           elif endPoint == False:
               rect = (rect[0], rect[1], x, y)
               endPoint = True

   cap = cv2.VideoCapture('../videos/sample.avi')
   waitTime = 50

   #Reading the first frame
   (grabbed, frame) = cap.read()

   while(cap.isOpened()):

       (grabbed, frame) = cap.read()

       cv2.namedWindow('frame')
       cv2.setMouseCallback('frame', on_mouse)    

       #drawing rectangle
       if startPoint == True and endPoint == True:
           cv2.rectangle(frame, (rect[0], rect[1]), (rect[2], rect[3]), (255, 0, 255), 2)

       cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

       key = cv2.waitKey(waitTime) 

       if key == 27:
           break

   cap.release()
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
   ```